# multiple images in div

Tags: css, image, rotatetransform

Could not find anything on this for the life of me. I simply want to display 1 little icon, multiple times on the same row, 
But want to rotate each instance a bit more then the last one. So by the end of the row, the last icon is completely flipped compared to the first icon.

Here is my attempt: (thanks)

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="one">I don't</p><p class="two">really want </p><p class="three">any</p><p class="four">words here</p>
</div>

<style>
p.one {
  float:left;
  image: url("http://www.itel.am/assets/ico/iconsForSocials/gl.png");
}
p.two {
  float:right;
  background-image: url("http://www.itel.am/assets/ico/iconsForSocials/gl.png");
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
p.three {
  float:right;
  background-image: url("http://www.itel.am/assets/ico/iconsForSocials/gl.png");
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
p.four {
  float:right;
  background-image: url("http://www.itel.am/assets/ico/iconsForSocials/gl.png");
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try position relative and move the element with top: 30px for example and left:50. ..100 and 150 for example

Answer (score 2):

Positioning system in a row can be achieved with 2 ways. The first and easy way is bootstrap grid system , so your problem could be solved like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3">img</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">img</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">img</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">img</div>
</div>
```

Replace the img keyword i wrote with your  images and transform them as you like inside css and you will be all set.

The second and more advanced way to place images in a row inside a div is position css attribute.

```
position:relative;
top:40px;
left:70px;
```

This will place the element in a specific place relative to its parent , so then you could place them wherever you want.

There are definitely more ways to do this like flexbox and more , but i totally recommend using bootstrap grid system because its easy to use and most of all responsive!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate the text from rotating. something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <p><span class="one"></span>I don't</p>
    <p><span class="two"></span>really want </p>
    <p><span class="three"></span>any</p>
    <p><span class="four"></span>words here</p>
</div>
```

and in css use image as background image

```
.container {width:100%}
.container p { float:left; margin:0 20px}
.container p span {
     width:20px; height:20px; display:block;
     background: url("http://www.itel.am/assets/ico/iconsForSocials/gl.png") no-repeat left center; float:left;
}
.two { transform: rotate(60deg); }
.three { transform: rotate(120deg); }
.four { transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

here is the working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/p0swkL7e/)